Cascading WFS through QGIS Server - SSL Handshake Failure
I'm trying to cascade a WFS from through QGIS Server, but I keep encountering an error. I've also tested this with other WFS services without success.
I'm using https://geoserver.plandata.dk/geoserver/wfs?servicename=wfs
The project sets up correctly, and the data loads in as expected. However, after saving the project and sending a request to my QGIS Server, I get an error with the following log message:
13:24:09 WARNING WFS[2928]: Download of capabilities failed: SSL handshake failed
13:24:09 WARNING WFS[2928]: GetCapabilities failed for url  pagingEnabled='true' 
preferCoordinatesForWfsT11='false' srsname='EPSG:25832' typename='pdk:theme_pdk_zonekort_v' 
url='https://geoserver.plandata.dk/geoserver/wfs?servicename=wfs' version='auto': Download of 
capabilities failed: SSL handshake failed
13:24:09 CRITICAL Server[2928]: Error, Layer(s) 
pdk_theme_pdk_zonekort_v_86c5a181_0942_4a0a_94b6_3a683257d6bb not valid in project 
D:\QGIS\qgis_server_projects\test4.qgs
13:24:09 WARNING Server[2928]: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServerException>Layer(s) not valid</ServerException>

Is there a solution to this issue, or is it simply not possible to achieve this setup?
QGIS Version:
3.28.10 - Firenze
